# What happened to Israel when Persia attacked Egypt?

Tags: bible

See Wiki :[Battle of Pelusium:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Pelusium_%28525_BC%29)

The Persians attacked Egypt while going through the territory which is today Israel:

What happened to that territory when this happened?

Who was the king?

Is this account mentioned in the bible?

Comment: Search "[Kingdom of Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Israel)" in wikipedia, you will see that there is none at 525 BC. Click on the most recent one that preceded 525 BC, [Kingdom of Judah 931–586 BCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Judah), you will find what happened at the end

Comment: So at that time, the bible story is Israel is in babylon. That's the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Christianity is a major religion. So I always want to know what happen to one important culture when an event happen. Why is this off topic?>

Comment: because they can be answered by looking up relevant topics on Wikipedia or Google.

Comment: not easily. Search where? Search for what? Israel pelusium? I've done that.

Comment: for example you can search "[History of Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Israel)" and see what happens at 525 BC.

Comment: I like this guy's question, because it shows an interest in the "white spaces on the map". That shows instincts of a true historian.

Comment: not sure what you mean by white spaces on the map. When things don't add up I often ask questions. It's just me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was no "Israel" at that time. The Kingdom of Judah was [conquered by Babylonia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish-Babylonian_war_%28601_BC-581_BC%29) at 587 BC, see [Siege of Jerusalem 587 BC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_%28587_BC%29). In 539 BCE the Persians conquered Babylonia, and [established the Yehud province](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Judah#Re-establishment), which were a peaceful part of the Achaemenid Persian Empire until the fall of the Empire in c. 333 BCE to Alexander the Great.

Wikipedia even has a section describing the biblical version of this period: [Biblical version of the Persian years (539-332 BCE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehud_Medinata#Biblical_version_of_the_Persian_years_.28539-332_BCE.29)